# Piggybacking extra data in H.264 blocks

Tags: video, video-streaming, h.264

I would like to add some additional descriptive labels to each macroblock of H.264 frames. The decoder will use dump these labels into a file. Does the H.264 standard support anything like this?

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No it doesn't, the macroblocks are tightly packed into the bitstream, many times using a fractional number of bits per macroblock.  One thing I've done in the past is with every coded slice NAL send an additional SEI NAL of payload type==5, which is unregistered user data.  These SEI NALs will be safely ignored by most proper h.264 decoders.  See Annex D of ITU-T H.264 specification for more info.